# How to disable menu wrap and enable horizontal scrolling on window resize?

Tags: css

First of all I am not programmer nor web developer.
Someone made a website for me but can not contact him right now.

After 3 days of googling i decided to post this question.

How to enable gorizontal scrolling instead of menu and footer wrap on window resize?

I tried attributes such as: display:inline-block; white-space: nowrap (i think this is related to text only), some JavaScripts.

I might placed these elements in wrong place as it's hard to know that code.

This is index file:
http://slawgd.webpark.pl/index.rtf

and pls find CSS here:
http://slawgd.webpark.pl/style.css

Thank you very much for you help!!

Greg

Comment: This is unwanted effect what i am talking about:
 [http://i.stack.imgur.com/if6H8.jpg

Answer (score 0):

**CAUTION:** I am sorry that my answer has no real solution so you can choose to ignore.

The followings are just my comment on your web page after I had analyzed it.

---

It would be **slightly** better if you copy the rendered code of HTML as we won't get your data in your SQL Database.

Simply right click the page in browser and find Source Code to get it.

Also, you might find a better answer from **the someone** who help you to produce it because he is the only one person familiarize your page most.

---

**EDIT:** Just a suggestion and not a solution.

After I looked at your page, it is suggested that to find **the someone** because the page was **complicated designed**.

It needs **lots of effort** to modify it without affecting other component.

Moreover, it is quite **horrible** to work out on **cross-broswer compatibility** because the code is not well designed.

In mainland China, users of Firefox might not have much, but there are still numbers of users using **Maxthon** which include **WebKit** engine.

Variant IE-based browser in mainland China also give a slightly different result of rendering so the code must be optimized.

Therefore, ask **the website editor** for cleaning the code (such as repeating CSS, malformed HTML structure, etc) and working hard on **cross-broswer compatibility** is **considerable**.

---

**More personal comment:**

In conclusion, if you find a worker for your website construction with **money** pay, it seems that it is a **huge job** to rewrite it and it is not easy to persuade him to help you.

Maybe you can ask **someone** to help you with a **simpler** basic structure and **insert** the original JS background slide effect and drop menu effect to your **newer, simpler, and cleaner** structure.

There are still a readable amount of unnecessary wrappers inside the page.

Comment: Thanks @tytsim for your answer. First, the code you can find here: gregkowal.com/index1.txt.

Comment: Second, I am on budget, so it'd difficult for me to pay to clear up the code. I lost contact with the guy who developed my website so i am trying to solve problems on the website by myself. Third, I know the code looks complicated, as with my suggestions webd eveloper used different methods to satisfy my expectations. I helped him to find a good solution and he used that. Code also doesn't look easy because web developer has created hand-made PHP CMS panel.

Comment: Fourth, you are right about campability issues. Most Chinese don't use Firefox. They use 360, IE, safari etc. I found that this website works well in FF only and that's real problem. I said this to Web developer but he ignored this. This project took 4 months to finish. and it didn't finish well as you can see. Website is very slow in China but i think that's server issue. However the most important is this "wrapping", i.e on Macbook and most of laptops with small resolution look horrible